# FIWARE Orion Notification

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We had Fiware Orion running on local instance - we had issue with notification received.

We need a way to append an identifier with callback url like http://localhost:1028/orion_callback.php?car_id=car_1 or get some data along with call back as Post/Get data.

How do we identify notification recieved for this attribute change ?

Comment: Not sure of undestanding the problem, sorry... could you elaborate a bit more on the specific problem do you have with the subscription, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the subscription to which a notification belongs (thus, related with an entity/attribute change) by the `subscriptionId` field in the notification payload body.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about adding query parameters to notification URL (i.e. `car_id=car1` in your example) you can use custom notifications in NGSIv2.

Based in the example in the question and assuming that `car1` refers to entity id you could use something like this:

```
"httpCustom": {
  "url": " http://localhost:1028/orion_callback.php",
  "qs": {
    "car_id": "${id}"
  }
}
```

Have a look to "Custom Notifications" section in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable) for details.